# Graphics Fill algorithm - get border

Tags: algorithm, graphics

Can anyone suggest me an algorithm which instead of filling an area, returns me a list of points which are "border" of this area?

Comment: I think a classic "flood fill" that added a point to a list if the point had at least one non-fill neighbor would work. Of course the points wouldn't be in order.

Comment: fits more here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to find the [Convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of a point set, then find the supporting points of the convex hull.

You can actually reuse the C++ [CGAL library](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Convex_hull_2/Chapter_main.html) for this purpose (which is IMO state of the art in that field).

Answer (score 1):

[Flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), or you can process your image and traverse edges. Depends on your input.